# Declaration of control

Tags: c#, wpf, math

I need help in a Math logic issue.
Let say I have an object that can be manipulate (move) by user.
After the user moved the object I would like the object to continue moving and decelerate to a stop.

Example, when a user move an object from point A to B with a total distance of 100pixel in X axis, after user release a finger, I want to let the object continue moving and decelerate to a stop from point B to point C.

So how can I calculate the new distance of point C if I set the time for it to decelerate and stop in 2sec?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

d = ½at² + v<sub>i</sub>t + d<sub>0</sub>

d<sub>0</sub> is the point at which the user "let go". Calculate v<sub>i</sub> from the motion before letting go. Set a to something negative; you'll have to fiddle with this to get it to feel right. Increment t from 0 through 2. d is where the object will end up. Remember that a and v<sub>i</sub> are **vectors** pointing in opposite directions, and that d<sub>0</sub> and d are **points**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But can you translate it into C# code so I can understand more clearly? Let me know if you need any value, if not you can assume. Thank you very much. (:

Comment: The acceleration will be different in every run. The code cannot "fiddle with [a] to get it to feel right" every time; we must *solve the equation*. -1

Comment: You're saying that "-0.1*v_i" isn't something one should come up with after testing?

Comment: Did you come up with -1.0*v_i by testing ("fiddling"), or by theory? (And it should be -0.5*v_i.) And if by testing, how did you decide on the *form* of the answer, kv_i, not k*v_i^2 or k*v_i+c?

Answer (score 0):

If the acceleration, a,  is constant you can use the formula:

d =  ½at²

With t = 2s you get d = 2a.

The acceleration is enough to accelerate to v in 2s,
so a = v/2.

You get:

d = v

So if v= 100 pixels per second, the object should continue 100 pixels if it stops in 2 seconds under constant deceleration.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the *distance* from **B** to **C**, that's easy. If the object went a distance N pixels (say 100) from **A** to **B** in k seconds, then the distance from **B** to **C** will be N/k.

If you want the *location* of **C**, so that A, B and C are integers on the x-axis, C = B+(B-A)/k.

If you want to *animate* the motion, so that you can update the position x at every time step dt (say 0.1 seconds), then start (at **B**) with v=N/k, and at each step,

```
x += v * dt
v -= N * dt/(2 * k)
```

(Be sure to use floats, not integers, or the round-off error will ruin the effect.)